# prototype property of class methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
class C { foo() {} }
C.prototype.foo // function foo() {}
C.prototype.foo.prototype // undefined - why?
```

Why is the `.prototype` property of class methods not set when created via the class method syntax?

Comment: What do you expect that to be?

Comment: Because JavaScript attempts to hide/cover-up the power of prototypal inheritance while not providing true classical inheritance with the `class` keyword. It's the worst of both worlds, tbh.

Comment: I expect it to be an object per a normal function declaration (I think).

Comment: Only constructor functions (and classes) have prototypes.

Comment: `__proto__` (dunder proto) gives a prototype reference, but has been deprecated in favor of `Object.getPrototypeOf()`, which is awkward to chain, but doable.

Comment: Ran the above code in Chrome developer tools and C.prototype.foo.prototype is returning an object.

Comment: @vabii Just ran it in Chrome console, getting undefined.

Comment: @mhodges I must be doing something wrong here - https://jsfiddle.net/vabii/ho2taax8/

Comment: @vabii You didn't "run the above code"... you changed the code and added a definition on the `C` prototype to include a definition for `foo` lol

Comment: @mhodges...oops, my bad.. thanks for clarifying..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because methods (like arrow functions) are no constructors, and don't need a `.prototype` from which the prototype of instances would be initialised, none will get created.

This is a new feature in ES6, which distinguishes method definitions in object literals and `class` definitions from usual `function` definitions.