# Why does a method using the shorthand method syntax not contain a prototype object

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

In the code snippet below `func2` is supposed to be [the shorthand method syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) for `func1`.

**Question 1**: Why does `obj1` contain the `prototype` Object and `obj2` does not (while both have the `__proto__` object)?

**Question 2**: Are all three objects prototype objects?

**Question 3**: Why does the fact of `obj2` not having a prototype function not influence the way in which it binds `this`?

**Concerning `obj3`**: `obj3` is there for reference because it is equivalent to `obj2` in terms of not having a `prototype` function. It just binds `this` differently (In `obj1` and `obj1` `this` is determined "by the invocation, but not by the enclosing context" and in `obj3` `this` is lexically bound to the `window` object. Both is [nicely described in this article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/).).

*The code snippet*:

```js
// Using the basic method definition
const obj1 = {
  foo: function() {
    console.log("This is foo");
  },
  bar: function() {
    console.log("This is bar");
    this.foo();
  }
};

// Using shorthand method syntax
const obj2 = {
  foo() {
    console.log("This is foo");
  },
  bar() {
    console.log("This is bar");
    this.foo();
  }
};

// Using arrow function
const obj3 = {
  foo: () => console.log("This is foo"),
  bar: () => {
    console.log("This is bar"); this.foo();
  }
};


/* Test */
obj1.bar(); // works!
obj2.bar(); // works!
obj3.bar(); // throws TypeError (this.foo is not a function)
```

*How I found that `func1` is a prototype function and `func2` not*:

I looked at both in the console of Chrome Dev Tools and found the `prototype` object only contained in one of them:

[image: Screenshot of console with obj1 and obj2]

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript) question about the difference between `__proto__` and `prototype` but my question here is about why the later is not present after using a syntax which should be equivalent.

Comment: Arrow functions don't have their own context, so you can't treat them like normal member methods unless their declaration is scoped inside a constructor or another member method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch) Spoiler: _**No**_, they're not.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does `obj1.bar` contain the `.prototype` Object and `obj2.bar` does not?

Because it's a method definition. Methods are no constructors, they don't need one. (It's the same [for `class` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44117363/1048572) and [for arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31947622/1048572), btw.)
In `obj2` you used a `function` expression, which creates a function that can be used as a constructor (as has been always the case in ES5).

> Are all three objects prototype objects?

An object is not a "prototype object". Every object can be used as the prototype of some other object or not.

> Why does the fact of `obj2.bar` not having a `.prototype` not influence the way in which it binds this?

Why would it? It's still a method that is supposed to have a dynamic `this` value, otherwise it could not be shared.

Only the arrow functions that you used in `obj3` have special behaviour in this regard. See [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31095710/1048572) for details.