# What is the difference between object method and shortened object method syntax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods

I have been studying JS OOP recently, and stopped on the following line (quote):

```
// these objects do the same

user = {
  sayHi: function() {
    alert("Hello");
  }
};

// method shorthand looks better, right?
user = {
  sayHi() { // same as "sayHi: function()"
    alert("Hello");
  }
};
```

> To tell the truth, the notations are not fully identical. There are
> subtle differences related to object inheritance (to be covered
> later), but for now they do not matter. In almost all cases the
> shorter syntax is preferred.

I haven't found an answer to this question.
So, What are the subtle differences between these 2 notations?

Comment: "*object inheritance*"? That's a weird way to put it. They are lacking a `.prototype` and cannot be used with `new`.

Comment: What book/tutorial/course are you reading? Please cite the source of your quote. Also, did you skip ahead to the section where it is actually explained?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Why does a method using the shorthand method syntax not contain a prototype object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891399/why-does-a-method-using-the-shorthand-method-syntax-not-contain-a-prototype)

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that the quoted text is talking about the fact that a function expression like this cannot use `super`:

```js
const object = {
  toString: function () {
    return "Hello World! " + super.toString();
  }
};
```

While the shorthand can use `super`:

```js
const object = {
  toString() {
    return "Hello World! " + super.toString();
  }
};

console.log(object.toString());
```

See: [MDN Using `super.prop` in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#Using_super.prop_in_object_literals)